# How to save class results in django cache and use it in other class

Tags: django

Html search file

```html
    <div class="content-section">
        <h1 class="mb-3">{{ user.username }}</h1>
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'doctor:search' %}">
                <input name ="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search..">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

`VIEWS.py` i like to save 'query' value in cache and use it later in different views.py class

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
      *query = self.request.GET.get('q')*
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to use query value in other class in views.py  [query = self.request.GET.get('q')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render_to_response` for returning multiple objects like that:

```
def get_queryset(self):  # new
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
    another_object_list = Doctor.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
    context = {
    'object_list': object_list,
    'another_object_list': another_object_list
    }
    return render_to_response('search.html', context)
```

And you can call this context in your template:

{{ object_list }}
{{ another_object_list }}

Comment: This is not what i need. I have multiple class which uses            `def get_queryset(self): 
query = self.request.GET.get('q')                                       object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
return object_list`.                                                                            I want to use query value in those class without using html template again. I like get query value once `query = self.request.GET.get('q')` and use it in other class without using `query = self.request.GET.get('q')` again in other class

Comment: Basically i want use one html file to get  [[[  query = self.request.GET.get('q')  ]]]  once and use this query value in all other class