# How to save search result to a model

Tags: django

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    comment = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patient')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('public:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

HTML search

```
<div class="content-section">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'public:home' %}">
                <input name ="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search..">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

VIEWS.py

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list
```

**I want to save this object_list in "patient" model.** How can i save search  result to model.
Is there any different method to search user and save to model?

Comment: can you post your Patient model?

Comment: patient is under post model, i have posted it on the top [patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patient')]

Comment: @HiroshiFuu https://stackoverflow.com/q/59027455/12376621 can you help me with this.